# Keep map text inside of map layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I have labeled a map.

The problem is that the text is outside of the map in some places.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view your map in "layout" view, you should be able to extend your data window to the page parameters of your document and the labels will reset to not leave the 'printable' page. This way if you export the map in layout view, all the pertinent info should be within your set boundaries.